# How does long long syntax work when int int doesn't in C++?

Tags: c++, data-types

I was wondering if long long specifies a single datatype then why don't things like int int work?  I meant obviously that's not a data type but there is a long data type.  Essentially what I'm asking is:

```
int a = 0; //okay
long b = 0; //still fine
long long c = 0; //really long number but its okay....
int int d = 0; //error
```

why?

Comment: That's because the language standard says so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between `long long` and `int int` is that `long` modifies a type, rather than being a type itself. `long` is really a shorthand for `long int` and `long long` a shorthand for `long long int`.

More specifically `int` is a type *specifier*, just like `char` or `bool`. `long` is a type *modifier*. Other type modifiers are `unsigned` and `signed` and `short`.

If one of the modifiers is missing then the type will fall back to a default. E.g. if there is no `signed` or `unsigned` then the type will be signed. If there is no `short` or `long` the default size depends on the compiler and the architecture.

Take a look at [this table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) for a full list of how different type specifiers and modifiers can be combined.

**Edit:**

In current versions of the *C* and *C++* standards `long` and `short` are actually type specifiers in their own right. This doesn't change the way that things can be combined though.

Comment: Note that originally, C defaulted types to int in many circumstances if they weren't specified. That "long" is shorthand for "long int" is a special case of that. There's also "short" -> "short int", "unsigned" -> "unsigned int" and the fact that in original C (before ANSI standardisation) function parameter and return types could be omitted and would default to int, too.

Comment: Technically, your notion about `long` being a modifier and `int` a specifier is not correct. Both are listed as type specifiers in modern C and C++ standards; there is no such thing as type modifiers. The standards also list all possible combinations of type specifiers, including `long long`, `long long int`, `signed long long`, `signed long long int` (all four synonymous), but not `int int`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I didn't know that. Looks like I'm harking back to the old days of C. `long` and `int` are both instances of a `simple-type-specifier` in the current C++ grammar.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a long integer that is longer than a `long` as `long long`.

But what would it mean to specify an integer that is more integer than `int`?

More precisely. In C++ you have type `int`, which is normally a 32-bit wide integer. You then have the modifiers `short` and `long` that can be used as illustrated by the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "short int:     " << sizeof(short int) << endl;
    cout << "short:         " << sizeof(short) << endl;
    cout << "int:           " << sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << "long int:      " << sizeof(long int) << endl;
    cout << "long:          " << sizeof(long) << endl;
    cout << "long long int: " << sizeof(long long int) << endl;
    cout << "long long:     " << sizeof(long long) << endl;
}
```

On my Linux box, running `g++ 4.7.2`, this gives:

```
short int:     2
short:         2
int:           4
long int:      8
long:          8
long long int: 8
long long:     8
```

So:

- `int` is a 32-bit signed integer
- `short int` (abbreviated, `short`) is a 16-bit signed integer
- `long int` (abbreviated, `long`) is a 64-bit signed integer
- `long long int` (abbreviated, `long long`) is still a 64-bit signed integer on my architecture / compiler, but it is in the language to allow a longer integer type (e.g. 128 bit) on different architectures / compilers.

So, as Will has explained: in this context, `long` is a modifier that can be applied twice whereas `int` is not a modifier.